# How to run devcoin-qt?

Tags: qt, executable

Anyone know how to open devcoin-qt? I tried running it by double-clicking it but nothing happened. I shutdown the `devcoind` and tried it - nothing. I renamed the `~/.devcoin` folder to `.devcoin.old` and got a popup that says:

> Could not display "devcoin-linux-a64". There is no application
>   installed for "executable" files. Do you want to search for  an
>   application to open this file?

I clicked yes, it selected and installed pypar2 - wrong - so now which program should be the default for opening an executable? - aptURL?, something else?

And I'm back to original issue - how to run the executable devcoin-qt file?
The file's permissions are set to my account & group.

Answer (score 1):

OK, looks like there were a couple of missing dependencies.

When I ran the `devcoin-qt` under my user account there was nothing that appeared to happen, but when I ran the file from the terminal using `sudo` a couple of dependencies showed up as missing: `libjpeg.so.62` and `libtiff.so.4`.

The first one was resolved by installing the libjpeg62 package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

I found the second solution online - create a symbolic link for `libtiff.so.4` to `libtiff.so.3`, but since I have `libtiff5` installed already, I used `libtiff.so.5`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
```

One other noteworthy point is that if `daemon=1` is set in the `devcoin.conf` file, then the GUI will not show, removing the `daemon=1` line from the `.conf` file corrects this and the GUI opens as expected.

Comment: Mark this answer as accepted (you can accept your own answers). Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). Do the same with your [other questions](http://askubuntu.com/users/342116/newbuntu1?tab=questions).